# Network interface on ubuntu with only 0.12MB/ s on a new root server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04

---- edit: Problem solved. Somehow my provider seems to block tests to the internet. Tests from a remote machine succeeded with 1k r/s ---

I am running a fresh compiled version of Apache 2.2.1 on ubuntu 10.04.03 LTS. The root-server has 32GB RAM and is a i7-2600k. The about same hardware and software is available for testing inside a virtual box on the intranet.

While the test server works great, serving about 800 concurent transactions/sec the "real" server on the internet just serves about 15 transactions per/second.

Running siege against it with: sudo siege -b -c50 -d10 -i http:/... the server starts serving files OK, but then after about 20-40s it gets slower and slower until it gets almost a halt.

unix top shows the apache process starting to span, but soon they ALL disapear, while the system only is running on load average of 0.1 - 0.3 Almost no resources are used. The process eat about 0-1% CPU.

configuration of httpd.conf is about the same as on the test server. I also tried to change some values that make sense but that did not help.

After experiencing the same problem with nginx I did run a network benchmark with netperf that returned from a remote location successfully 600MB/s, but from the intranet only 0.13MBs

Does anybody have an idea how to aproach that problem. I am maintaining linux systmes no for 10 years and have never seen something similar before.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

With the curiosity of why you've chosen to compile instead of using a prebuilt package for your environment, have you ensured that you have swap enabled on the system? If it were RHEL, you should have physical+2G swap (34G in your case).

Are any odd plugins or unusual mod_* items configured and running (java, etc)?

The most probable area to look at in my opinion I to ensure you've compiled the package properly (or use one from a public repository for your platform), and make sure swap is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have a duplex mismatch somewhere in your network. You have a switch hard set to full duplex which turns off the duplex negotiation protocol and a server set to auto-negotiate duplex. When it doesn't get an answer back from the switch, the server defaults to half-duplex, resulting in a mismatch. This will cause the horrid network performance you're seeing.